# Installing Adhesive Cement Tape

Tags: tile

Getting ready to tape my HardieBacker 1/2" cement boards.  Some instructions say to apply the the self-adhesive fiberglass tape (FibaTape in my case) to the boards, and go over it with thinset.

Others say to apply the thinset, and embed the tape into the thinset.

Does it matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either way will work, I do it without the initial layer of thinset. What matters the most is using a nice creamy thinset mix and applying it carefully in a wide band, to reduce the "hump" that could result in tiles that lay unevenly.

Comment: Agreed. There's no structural reason to apply thinset first, and it's far less messy to apply the tape first.